# PyGObject and glade send window to the front

Tags: python, glade, pygobject

im having some problems to send to the front a GTK window.

I have a main window (`window_root`) with a button that launches another window (`window_programs`).

with this commands:

```
window_root.hide()
window_programs.show()
```

then, in `window_programs`, i have a button that displays another window (`window_list`) with the command:

```
window_list.show()
```

`window_list` is modal.

The problem was that `window_list` appeared at the back of `window_programs`.
so i did some research and i found `window_list.show()`.

The problems is that `window_list` appears at the front, but when i click it `window_programs` comes to the front!

it makes some time that i'm looking for the solution, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [transient-for](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#GtkWindow--transient-for) property of the modal window (which should be available in Glade). If the modal window needs to be transient to either of the two other windows, then you need to use gtk_window_set_transient_for() as needed since the modal can only be transient for one window at a time.