# Python open window and set parent insensitive

Tags: python, window, gtk3

I am currently building an application with python 2.7 with Gtk3+.

I want to open a window on top of another window. If the second window is visible, the parent one should not be clickable.

So the behaviour should be the same like opening a dialog window.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the property `window.set_transient_for(parent_window)`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128192/pygobject-and-glade-send-window-to-the-front) post may help you if you are using glade.

Comment: This has no obvious effect here. I can click the buttons on the main window anyway. Both windows are from type Gtk.Window(TOPLEVEL).

Comment: Hummm.. can you upload the source? that should work